# Extract polygons using Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I'm trying to extract areas that have the tag `name = "Maroc Telecom` using Overpass Turbo, to do so I executed this query:

```
area
 [name="Maroc Telecom"];
out geom;
```

When I look at the data tab I find an xml file which contains the features of my query yet on the map I can't see these areas to export them as GeoJSON.

Here is the resulting XML from Overpass Turbo query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API 0.7.55.4 3079d8ea">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2018-08-27T14:38:02Z" areas="2018-08-27T13:42:02Z"/>

  <area id="2502675189">
    <tag k="amenity" v="telephone"/>
    <tag k="building" v="public_building"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Maroc Telecom"/>
    <tag k="shop" v="mobile_phone"/>
  </area>
  <area id="2643523107">
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Maroc Telecom"/>
  </area>
  <area id="2651330415">
    <tag k="addr:city" v="taza تازة"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Maroc Telecom"/>
    <tag k="office" v="telecommunication"/>
  </area>
  <area id="2681225147">
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Tanger"/>
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Maroc Telecom"/>
    <tag k="office" v="telecommunication"/>
  </area>
  <area id="2778063776">
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Maroc Telecom"/>
    <tag k="office" v="telecommunication"/>
  </area>
  <area id="2799103379">
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Ouarzazate"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="45000"/>
    <tag k="building" v="commercial"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Maroc Telecom"/>
    <tag k="office" v="telecommunication"/>
  </area>
  <area id="2854549079">
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Maroc Telecom"/>
    <tag k="office" v="telecommunication"/>
  </area>

</osm>
```

Comment: Does the XML contain geocoordinates? Can you post an example output?

Comment: No it doesn't contain the coordinates and I know that this is the source of the issue. I don't know how to have these areas displayed on the map so I can export them.

Comment: It's likely that the result of the query is NULL (no results). Are you certain that there are "area" polygons named "Maroc Telecom"?

Comment: Yes Im pretty sure that there are some areas named "Maroc Telecom". I did some researches directly in OSM.

Comment: It could be that there are other features named "Maroc Telecom" (e.g. "Buildings"). Areas could be open expanses of land (e.g. "Commercial", "Nature Reserve"). I would try using https://overpass-turbo.eu/ to get a better handle of how the OSM API works.

Comment: I'm using it but nothing is rendered https://overpass-turbo.eu/#. If you run the query you will get some results in the "Data" Tab yet no coordinates are returned that's why I can't see them on the map. I don't understand why yet I use the same code with nodes and it works without issues.

Comment: The output of the XML doesn't contain any geocoordinates (lon/lat), so that's probably why you aren't seeing anything on a map. I've revised your question to help shed light on why that is.

Answer (score 2):

The main use case for areas in Overpass API is to restrict further queries to certain polygons defined by some ways or relations. Your use case looks quite different: you're interested in ways / relations to generate some GeoJSON.

In this case you should query directly for the respective nodes, ways and relations, and use the Overpass Turbo Export feature to create GeoJSON output for it (Overpass API doesn't support GeoJSON!):

```
nwr[name="Maroc Telecom"];
out geom;
```